# relevant 4-dimensional theory with interacting vector field

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

A simple langragian that gives the simplest interaction is $\mathcal{L}=(\partial\phi)^2+(m\phi)^2$ where $m$ is some constant. Does anyone know of theory in four dimensions which is physically interesting and couples three vector fields over a 4-dim'l manifold.

Comment: what about $\mathcal{L}_{\text{I}} = \kappa \, \partial^{\alpha}A^{\beta}\partial_{\alpha}A^{\gamma}\partial_{\beta}A_{\gamma}$?  That seems like a lorentz invariant with three vector potentials.

Comment: thanks for the comment. do you know if such a term appears in the lagrangian for some physically relevant theory? that's the heart of my question. like you, i can write different terms that would be acceptable but i am interested in a theory which is already of some importance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't . . . but if you can make one that is Lorentz invariant, and, under a group of your choice, gauge invariant and self consistent, it's a good way to learn and have fun.

Comment: The hugely important example is Yang-Mills theory (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory or any passable QFT textbook). Nonabelian Yang-Mills theory has three and four point vertices for the gauge bosons. If you only want a three point vertex you'll have to go to Chern-Simons theory in three dimensions (http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9902115v1.pdf). I'm afraid I don't know of any well defined 4D theory which has 3-point vector couplings but not 4-point ones.

Comment: @MichaelBrown: I suppose that by well-defined, you mean UV complete? Otherwise, practically any Lagrangian will do.

Comment: @Vibert Yes, I should have specified that.